# What cause this message "unhandled in root state." in Android (4.1.2)?

Tags: android, mpeg2-ts

I’m using an Android application (On Android 4.1.2) which get a ts stream in input but I have only the audio and don't have the video.

I think it is due to this message:

```
avc_utils( 1040): found AVC codec config (480 x 270, Baseline-profile level 2.1)
OMXNodeInstance( 1040): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed

W/        ( 2591): Warning message AMessage(what = 'omx ', target = 5) = {

W/        ( 2591):   int32_t type = 0

W/        ( 2591):   void *node = 0x1

W/        ( 2591):   int32_t event = 3

W/        ( 2591):   int32_t data1 = 1

W/        ( 2591):   int32_t data2 = 117440527

W/        ( 2591): } unhandled in root state.
```

I want to understand what can cause this message *unhandled in root state*?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!